# Create an array with same element repeated multiple times in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

There is a array: `A={4,5}` , now I have to concatenate this array `X` times into an empty array `B`.

eg: if `x=3`
Then `B={4,5,4,5,4,5}`

This can be implemented like this:

```
    vector<int>B;
    while(x--){
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            B.push_back(A[i]);
        }
    }
```

`N` is length of array A.
 
When `X=N` this will take `O(N^2)`. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This will take `O(x*N)`. Seeing as the final vector must have `x*N` elements, I don't see how you expect a faster algorithm. Time complexity cannot possibly be smaller than space complexity.

Comment: You can replace the inner loop with `B.insert(B.end(), A.begin(), A.end());` It's still the same complexity, just shorter code.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes `insert` also gives same time complexity. Since i am defining A as a vector can I expand it? Like python has `[2]*5` gives `[2,2,2,2,2]`

Comment: Is your concern about the code being too verbose? Then write a function to encapsulate it, and it will be concise for future callers. Or is it about the algorithm being slow? Do you believe that Python somehow magically executes `[2]*5` in constant time? There ain't no free lunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is expand a `std::vector` as efficiently as possible then you could do something like :

```
template<typename T>
void expandVector(T& vec, const size_type noOfExpansions)
{
    const size_type sizeOfVec = vec.size();
    vec.reserve(noOfExpansions * sizeOfVec);
    for(int i = 0; i < noOfExpansions; ++i)
    {
        vec.insert(vec.end(), vec.begin(), vec.begin() + sizeOfVec);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately there isn't anything quite as expressive as `[2]*5` for `std::vector`s in this case, the best you can do is probably to trim a bit of the fat from the above example:

```
const size_type sizeOfVec = vec.size();
for(int i = 0; i < noOfExpansions; ++i)
{
     vec.insert(vec.end(), vec.begin(), vec.begin() + sizeOfVec);
}
```

You can also cut saving the size if like in your example, you want to copy and then expand.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can improve the order of magnitude beyond O(x*N).
But setting the initial vector size to

```
std::vector<int> B(x*N);
```

could slightly improve performance by reducing vector regrowth under certain conditions.

Comment: Of course, this will require changing the loop body (to use indexing instead of `push_back`), *and* it will zero out the vector at creation time, which incurs a runtime hit again. You might be better off setting the vector's capacity instead of its size.

Answer (score 2):

This will take `O(X*N)` in general so when *X = N*, it will take **`O(N*N)`**. You cannot improve the complexity from `O(N)` while inserting *N* elements in vector. However you can shorten your code to this:

```
vector<int>B,A={4,5};
int x=3;
while(x--)
    B.insert( B.end(), A.begin(), A.end() );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
int main()
{
  int k = 3;
  vector<int> v = {1,-2,3};
  vector<int> o;

  for (int i=0; i<k*v.size(); ++i) {
    o.push_back(v[i%v.size()]);
  }

  for (int i=0; i<o.size(); ++i) {
    cout<<o[i];
  }

  return 0;
}
```